# VBA code to calculate pick-up% up ownership chain

Tags: vba, excel

First time poster!

I am hoping someone can help with my a VBA code.  I have some experience with VBA coding, but I don't have the knowledge or expertise to handle the task I am facing.

I have a report of entities and their owners.

With this report, you can follow the ownership chain of each entity.

Here is an example of the Report:

```
Entity #,     Entity Name,     Parent #,     Parent Name,     Owner %    Inside
100           Entity 1         200           Entity2          100        Yes
200           Entity 2         300           Entity 3         50         Yes
200           Entity 2         400           Entity 4         50         Yes
500           Entity 5         600           Entity 6        100         Yes
600           Entity 6         700           Entity 7         25         Yes
600           Entity 6         800           Entity 8         25         Yes
600           Entity 6         900           Entity 9         50         Yes
800           Entity 8        1200           Entity 12       100         Yes
900           Entity 9        1000           Entity 10        25         No
900           Entity 9        1100           Entity 11        75         Yes
```

So basically, Entity one is owned 100% by Entity 2.  Entity 2 is owned by 50% by Entity 4 and Entity 5.  Entity 3 and 4  is not owned by any affiliates.  Entity 5 is owned 100% by Entity 6.  Entity 6 is owned 25% to Entity 7, 25% by entity 8 and 50% by entity 9 . Entity 8 is owned 100% by entity 12. Entity 9 is owned 25% by entity 10 and 75% by Entity 11.  Entity 10 is not an affiliate.

The code should calculate the Pick-up % of the lower entity [100 & 500].  In this case, the Pick-up % for 100 will be 100% because all of the entities in the chain are affiliates.  While the pick-up% for 500 is 75% because entity 1000 is not an affiliate.

I have started and stop writing this code at least ten times and each time I get stuck along the way.  Here is my issue: In reality, the chain could go up 7 to 8 levels.  Once I get back past level two, I do not know how to calculate the pickup % of the entity has multiple owners.  For instance, if you look at my table up top. Once I calculate the ownership for 600, I can't figure how to extend the chain to owners of 800 and 900.

Here is a diagram of the ownership structures:

[image]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub ownerinterest()

    Sheets("Copyii").Activate

    Set dict3 = New Dictionary

    nRowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    arowcount = Cells(Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp).Row

    ReportArray = Range(Cells(1, "AA"), Cells(arowcount, "AB"))

    For i = 2 To nRowCount

        GemC = Left(Cells(i, "a"), 5)
        ParentC = Cells(i, "d")
        PctC = (Cells(i, "J") / 100)
        OwnerC = Cells(i, "h")
        EntityC = Cells(i, "b")

        d = i

        If (Not (dict3.Exists(GemC))) Then

            Set GEMclass = New Gclass

            dict3.Add GemC, GEMclass

            dict3(GemC).e = EntityC
            dict3(GemC).P = ParentC
            dict3(GemC).O = OwnerC
            dict3(GemC).Num = d
            dict3(GemC).g = GemC

        End If

        Call countlevels

        dict3(GemC).Pct = PctC

    Next i

    Call Calculepickup

End Sub
Sub countlevels()

    For e = LBound(ReportArray, 1) To UBound(ReportArray, 1)

        If GemC = ReportArray(e, 1) Then

            If ReportArray(e, 2) > 1 Then

                Pcount = ReportArray(e, 2)

                PctC = 0

                For f = 1 To Pcount

                    TPct = Cells(i + f - 1, "J")

                    PctC = TPct + PctC

                Next f

                Exit For

            Else

                PctC = PctC

                Exit For

            End If

        End If

    Next e

End Sub
Sub Calculepickup()

    Dim g As Long, h As Integer, j As Integer, m As Integer
    Dim NewGem As String
    Dim Tpct2 As Double
    Dim MainArray() As Variant
    Dim MainRange As Range

    m = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set MainRange = Range("a1:J" & m)
    MainArray() = MainRange

    For g = 0 To dict3.Count - 1

        Set GEMclass = dict3.Items(g)

        ReportGEM = GEMclass.P
        GemC = GEMclass.g
        PctC = GEMclass.Pct

        Debug.Print GemC & "|" & ReportGEM & "|" & PctC

        For h = 0 To dict3.Count - 1

            If (dict3.Exists(ReportGEM)) Then

                NewGem = ReportGEM

                For j = LBound(ReportArray) To UBound(ReportArray)

                    If NewGem = ReportArray(j, 1) Then

                        If ReportArray(j, 2) > 1 Then

                            Pcount = 0
                            Pcount = ReportArray(j, 2)
                            Tpct2 = 0

                            Dim K As Integer

                            For K = LBound(MainArray, 1) To UBound(MainArray, 1)

                                Dim GEMk As String
                                GEMk = MainArray(K, 1)

                                If NewGem = GEMk Then
                                    Debug.Print GEMk & "|" & K

                                    For f = 1 To Pcount

                                        TPct = Cells(K + f - 1, "J")

                                        Debug.Print TPct

                                        Tpct2 = TPct + Tpct2
                                        Debug.Print Tpct2

                                    Next f
                                    Exit For

                                End If

                            Next K

                        End If

                    End If

                Next j

            End If

        Next h
    Next g

End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't entity #500 be 87.5% owned by the group?  Entity #1000 owns 25% of entity #900, but entity #900 owns only 50% of entity #600, so therefore entity #1000 owns 25% of 50% [12.5%] of entity #600.  And then entity #600 owns 100% of entity #500, so entity #1000 therefore only owns 12.5% of entity #500.

Comment: I guess i didn't do a go job explaining this.  All of the entities with the exception of 1000 is owned by the same Parent entity.  For example, 500 is has three owners but since all three are indirectly owned by the parent all three are included.

Comment: But how do you want to calculate what percentage of #500 is owned by the "Parent entity".  If Entity #1000 owned 100% of entity #900 which owned only 1% of entity #500, would you say that entity #500 has a pickup of 0% (because #1000 owns 100% of #900) even though most of the ownership of #500 is by other entities?  Or would you say that the pickup is 99% because only 1% of it is owned by outside entities?

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying, Yes, 500 would be 87.5%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the following will do what you want.  (It's probably the only real way to associate an "ownership percentage" based on multiple parents each with their own "ownership percentage".)

```
Public entities As New Dictionary
Public MainArray() As Variant

'I have assumed that the table you posted in the question represented columns A to F of an Excel spreadsheet.
'Change the following constants so it suits your actual layout. 
Const colEntity As Integer = 1   ' Assumed column A
Const colParent As Integer = 3   ' Assumed column C
Const colPct As Integer = 5      ' Assumed column E
Const colInside As Integer = 6   ' Assumed column F

Sub Calculepickup()

    Dim g As Integer, r As Integer, m As Integer
    Dim MainRange As Range

    m = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set MainRange = Range("a2:J" & m)
    MainArray() = MainRange


    'Add each entity to a dictionary, and flag the percentage as uncalculated by setting it to -1
    For g = 1 To UBound(MainArray, 1)
        If Not entities.Exists(MainArray(g, colEntity)) Then
            entities.Add MainArray(g, colEntity), -1
        End If
        If Not entities.Exists(MainArray(g, colParent)) Then
            If MainArray(g, colInside) = "No" Then
                'If the entity isn't "inside" store the fact that it is 0% owned
                entities.Add MainArray(g, colParent), 0
            Else
                entities.Add MainArray(g, colParent), -1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    r = 0
    For Each e In entities.Keys
        CalculatePct e

        'Write results to columns N and O just so that we can see them
        r = r + 1
        Cells(r, 14) = e
        Cells(r, 15) = entities(e)
    Next
End Sub

Sub CalculatePct(e As Variant)
    Dim g As Integer
    Dim pct As Double
    Dim Owned100Pct As Boolean
    If entities(e) < 0 Then
        pct = 0
        Owned100Pct = True  ' Keeps track if the entity exists in the table other than as a parent

        For g = 1 To UBound(MainArray, 1)
            If MainArray(g, colEntity) = e Then
                Owned100Pct = False

                If entities(MainArray(g, colParent)) = -1 Then
                    'If we don't know the parent's ownership percentage, go and calculate it
                    CalculatePct MainArray(g, colParent)
                End If

                pct = pct + CDbl(MainArray(g, colPct)) / 100 * entities(MainArray(g, colParent))
            End If
        Next

        If Owned100Pct Then
            'Assume 100% owned if we don't know the parentage
            '("Outside" entities won't go through here as they are already set to 0%)
            entities(e) = 1
        Else
            'Store the entity's percentage
            entities(e) = pct
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Oops - Just noticed I was still using a variable of `j` in a couple of spots, even after I edited the code (after pasting from my test spreadsheet) to dimension it as `r` instead.  Fixed now.