# VBA: How to a edit a code to eliminate the out of stack space error?

Tags: excel, vba

This code used to work, but recently I am getting an error (out of stack space).

I think the code is failing because I am calling a function too many times without exiting/ending.

If that is the case, how many times can you call a function and is there something I can do to fix this?

I am not the original author of this code.

I included the sub where the error occurs.

```
    Sub CalculatePct(e As Variant)
        Dim G As Integer
        Dim pct As Double
        Dim Owned100Pct As Boolean
        If entities(e) < 0 Then

            pct = 0
            Owned100Pct = True  ' Keeps track if the entity exists in the table other than as a parent

            For G = 1 To UBound(MainArray, 1)
                If MainArray(G, colEntity) = e Then

                    Owned100Pct = False

                    If entities(MainArray(G, colParent)) = -1 Then
                        'If we don't know the parent's ownership percentage, go and calculate it
                        CalculatePct MainArray(G, colParent)    
                    End If

                    pct = pct + CDbl(MainArray(G, colPct)) / 100 * entities(MainArray(G, colParent))

                End If
            Next

            If Owned100Pct Then
                'Assume 100% owned if we don't know the parentage
                '("Outside" entities won't go through here as they are already set to 0%)
                entities(e) = 1
            Else
                'Store the entity's percentage
                entities(e) = pct
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Your recursion is too deep - the call stack stores all the "in progress" methods (someone else feel free to jump in with a more precise description) and you're maxing it out.  It's possible your code is entering an endless loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A @TimWilliams noted in the comments - you have an endless recursion loop.

Highlighting the problem area:

```
Sub CalculatePct(e As Variant)
[...]
                If entities(MainArray(G, colParent)) = -1 Then
                    CalculatePct MainArray(G, colParent)    
                End If
[...]
End Sub
```

`e` is the parameter, and `entities(e)` is checked. In the code, `MainParent(G, colParent)` is used in place of `e`, so the next call to the routine gives `e` = `MainParent(G, colParent)`.

Up to the point in the code, you do not change the value of `G`, `colParent`. `entities` or `MainArray`. So if `entities(MainArray(G, colParent)) = -1` it will be forever calling itself.

Without knowing anything else about the code (including if recursion is necessary) I cannot suggest any definitive solutions. However, some things to consider:

- Rewriting to be a loop instead of a recursive call
- Making the recursive call to a subset of `MainArray`
- Doing any amendments to `G` or `colParent` prior to the recursive
  call

Comment: As I mentioned before, the code worked with prior data.  However, In the past the code calculated ownership % for 300 companies - now there are 700 companies.  I don't know how to fix it.  I am not a VBA expert and I am not the author of this code. I can follow it and make little changes, but I can't figure out how to make it work. Here is a link to my original post. Maybe it will make things more clear. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961560/vba-code-to-calculate-pick-up-up-ownership-chain]

Comment: @FreddieFred: (1) The prior data was probably clean, or maybe luck played a part. If you have not changed the code at all, then that problem has existed for a while! The good news is that you now know there is an issue and it can be fixed. Much worse if you have a data processing error and nobody knows that the error is happening!

Comment: @FreddieFred: (2) Each Q&A should stand on its own. If there is important background or explanation, then it should be edited into the question.

Comment: @FreddieFred: (3) StackOverflow is not a code writing service. I have identified the problem area and have three suggestions to fix it. If you encounter any difficulties when you try the approach, you can open a new specific question.

Comment: @FreddieFred: (Bonus Point) A quick glance at your 2016 post tells me you are trying to do too much at the same time. You are effectively analysing a network (not a tree or binary structure). First build your network (e.g. using a double-linked list with a collection of nodes for both Parents and Children) and then traverse the network (not the raw Excel data) to get your answers. What this comment means is that you should go back to the basics to rebuild your application - which is usually not as bad as it sounds.

Comment: You suggestions are very helpful.  I will take a look at the code and try to apply them.  Once again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've offered no indication of what line the error occurs on nor what MainArray represents but I'm guessing that MainArray has grown to a size greater than what can be accessed with a signed short integer.

Change the declaration of your iteration variable to a Signed Long Integer. This raises the functional limit of the variable from 32,767 iterations to 2,147,483,647.

```
Dim G As Long
```